# Getting jcifs.smb.SmbException: The handle is invalid while copying products

Tags: java, jcifs

I have written code to copy *.dmg,*.exe files from a smb server in java. I am using JCIFS library to copy the products, while it is working fine while copying dmg files, it is returning a strange error while copying windows products and crashing.

> jcifs.smb.SmbException: The handle is invalid.
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:563)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:663)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
>       at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)

Does anyone have any idea why it is happening, and what I can do to prevent it?

Comment: What is your current code?